# Is it possible to insert two date values into a SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: android, date, time, simpledateformat

In my app I used to have a time picker and a date picker. The date and time was stored using SimpleDateFormat. 
It looked like this:

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm:ss";

new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

Now I want to make some changes and instead of having a time and a date picker I would like to have two date pickers. The problem is that I cannot store two dates like that. 
Why is this not possible:

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy dd-MM-yyyy";

new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

Comment: Where are you storing the dates?  SimpleDateFormat cannot store the date, it only stores the format.  When you get your date (or time, or both) you need to have it saved into some variables.  And, yes, you can use the same SimleDateFormat for formatting both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but having 2 date pickers on your screen implies 2 objects. Each with their own format (which may, or may not be, the same).

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";

public static SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
public static Date date1 = new Date();
public static Date date2 = new Date();

static {
    System.out.println(format.format(date1));
    System.out.println(format.format(date2));
}
```